# present perfect and present continuous in one sentence

Tags: tense, present-perfect, present-continuous

The present perfect and present continuous are a little bit challenging for me.

Here:

> How are you feeling today? I hope you **have fully recovered** and **you are having** a good start of the week. If this is the case, would [day of the week, month, day, and time] still be a good time to visit your lab?

Context: I was invited for an interview, but the two individuals that I was supposed to meet with got sick, and they asked to postpone the interview for the following week. In the above sentence, I am following up with them prior to the interview. **So,** is it grammatically correct to use the present perfect and present continuous in the same sentence?

Comment: Yes, that's good, Moe. It's grammatically correct, but you could leave out the second *you*: **I hope you have fully recovered and are having...**

Comment: Thanks for your replay! Would you please explain what the sentence means to you in terms of using both tenses?

Comment: I don't understand your question. You *know* what it means. It doesn't mean anything different to *me*.